# Unable to invoke Chrome and other browsers dynamically by giving the values in settings

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I was unable to access the Chrome driver, and when I executed the below code, it failed. However even with the Chrome browser, I observed that it opens with an empty Firefox driver. Could anyone please help me ?

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    to validate the login form
Library    SeleniumLibrary
#Resources

*** Test Cases ***
Validate unsuccessful Login
   Open Browser    with the Mortgage payment url
   #Fill the Login form
   #Wait Until it checks and display the error message
   #verify error message is correct

*** Keywords ***
open the browser with the Mortgage payment url


    open the browser with the Mortgage payment url
    Create Webdriver     Chrome     executable_path=C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\test\resources\chromedriver.exe
    Go To   https://rahulshettyacademy.com/loginpagePractise/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryJnq.png)

I want to access the given url from the robot framework.

Comment: **whitespaces matter**  On first testcase, you have `Open Browser    with the Mortgage payment url` .. that translates to `Open Browser` keyword which defaults to firefox and then passes `with the Mortgage payment url` as an argument for that keyword.

Comment: Second, selenium can download the chromedriver and locate it automatically since 4.0..  IF you are not passing any arguments, you dont need to `Create Webdriver`, you can just pass proper argument for `Open Browser` keyword.

Comment: Third, your keyword `open the browser with the Mortgage payment url` -- as it was typed in your question will call itself -- probably causing a crash ..